# How to add condition in os path (python) to list files after 2012 only

Tags: python, list, os.path

I have below code which list all files in folder and subfolder. I want to add code which list only those files which are modified after 2012

```
path=r'c:\xx\download'
files_sorted_by_date = []
filenm=[]
filept=[]
creation=[]
filepaths=[]
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        filepaths.append(os.path.join(root,file))

file_statuses = [(os.stat(filepath), filepath) for filepath in filepaths]

files = ((status[stat.ST_MTIME], filepath) for status, filepath in file_statuses if stat.S_ISREG(status[stat.ST_MODE]))

for creation_time, filepath in sorted(files):
    creation_date = time.ctime(creation_time)
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    filept.append(filepath)
    filenm.append(filename)
    creation.append(creation_date)
    files_sorted_by_date.append(creation_date + "," + filename)

    #print(files_sorted_by_date)

df =pd.DataFrame(files_sorted_by_date,columns=['files'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the time in seconds since 1970 with `os.path.getmtime(path)`

you can convert it to a tuple with `time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(path))`

the output would be something like this `(2006, 8, 17, 12, 6, 3, 3, 229, 1)`

now you can get the first value of the tuple (the year).

```
year = time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(path))[0]
```